# Error: P3017 When I run npx prisma command

Tags: next.js, prisma

when I hit  `npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init` in command line. bellow error occurred:

**Error: P3017

The migration 0_init could not be found. Please make sure that the migration exists, and that you included the whole name of the directory. (example: "20201207184859_initial_migration")**

I want to use mysql tables in my own next js project .

According to [this](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project/relational-databases/baseline-your-database-typescript-postgresql) url, I can do that using prisma orm.

but Im stock in this step : `npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Change `migration.sql` file encoding to `window1252`.**

In VScode:

- Open the migration.sql file
- open command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and search for "Change File Encoding"
- select "Save with encoding"
- select "window1252"

---

From this thread : https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/17558

They found the issue was caused by migration.sql file encoding.
The file encoding is determined by the shell used when executing the `npx prisma migrate diff > migration.sql` command.

When executed in Powershell, it writes the migration.sql file using utf16 encoding. When executed in CMD it writes the file using window1252.

Comment: Bravo guy, You are the only one who solved my problem. thank you.

Comment: According to this answer we need to do these in cmd(run as administrator):

1- npx prisma migrate diff --from-empty --to-schema-datamodel prisma/schema.prisma --script > prisma/migrations/0_init/migration.sql

2- npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init

Answer (score 0):

I just encounted exactly the same issue as yours. My environment: VSCode1.78 on a Windows10 .
I was struck in my VSCode terminal, which by default is a powershell.

Fortunately I got inspiration from comments to the end of this thread:
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/17558

Then I switched to a "cmd" terminal in VSCode to execute the same command, and the problem just disappeared.

So I am sure the problem was caused by some difference between Powshell terminal and "cmd" terminal.

By the way, I tried the "npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init" command in a git bash terminal outside of VSCode. All good there too.

Comment: tnx for replies . I tried in both cmd and git bash in root of project location . but error persist